# How can I check that a library's main header includes all its sub-headers?

Tags: c++, cmake

I have a C++ project structure like:

```
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── include/
│   ├── lib.hpp
│   └── lib/
│       ├── a.hpp
│       ├── b.hpp
│       └── c.hpp
├── test/
```

I use CMake as build system builder. All header files have `#pragma once` for double include protection. `include/lib.hpp` should include all `.hpp` files from `include/lib/`.

How can I verify that all `include/lib/*.hpp` are directly or indirectly included by `lib.hpp`?

If testing indirect includes is difficult a test for direct includes is also fine. That's what `#pragma once` is supposed for at all. I just want to make sure that Continuous Integration kicks in when I add new header files and forget to include them in the main header.

I already have a test that works if an invalid file is included. This can happen when I rename or delete something. This is realized by a `.cpp` file which includes the main header and is compiled.

Comment: With `make VERBOSE=1` you could obtain the compile command line, and by replacing `-c` with `-E` you could obtain the preprocessed code (you could also replace value of `-o` for output preprocessing results into different file). The preprocessed code contains (in annotation-like comments) names of all header files which has been read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this would be pretty hard to do in a way that retains CMake's desirable property of multiple-platform support. Though I suppose you're technically boxing yourself a bit in already by usage of the non-standard `#pragma once`.

- One approach would be to have CMake use a compiler-specific feature to tell a compiler to create a pre-processed file, such as using [GCC's `-E` flag](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Overall-Options.html), and then have CMake scan that file to look for parts of the particular files. Keywords "*compiler-specific*".
- One approach would be to have CMake use a compiler-specific feature to tell a compiler to generate a depfile (file with info about `#include` dependencies and such), and scan the depfile to look for all the particular files. Ex. [GCC's `-MF` and related flags](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html) Keywords "*compiler-specific*".

I don't think CMake has some perfect feature to do what you want because CMake generally doesn't need such a feature to do its main job.

I'd suggest you look at a different approach (I think this is an XY problem): Instead of trying to get CMake to check that a file you manually wrote contains a bunch of structured `#include`s, just use CMake to generate such a file:

```
file(GLOB_RECURSE lib_part_headers
  RELATIVE "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/lib"
  CONFIGURE_DEPENDS
  "*.hpp"
)
message("lib_part_headers: ${lib_part_headers}")
set(lib_header "#pragma once")
foreach(lib_part_header ${lib_part_headers})
  if("${lib_part_header}" MATCHES "^\\.\\.")
    continue()
  endif()
  string(APPEND lib_header "#include \"lib/${lib_part_header}\"\n")
endforeach()
file(WRITE "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/include/lib.hpp" "${lib_header}")
target_include_directories(my_target PUBLIC "$<BUILD_INTERFACE:${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/include>")
install(DIRECTORY
  "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/include"
  TYPE INCLUDE
)
```

---

Note that if you don't use `#pragma once`, and instead use include guards with formulaic names, then you can use an approach like the following with [`try_compile`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/try_compile.html) and `static_assert`, where you just check that the include guard macros are defined (presumably your codebase is sane, and they will only be defined by including the corresponding header):

```
file(GLOB_RECURSE lib_part_headers
  RELATIVE "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/lib"
  CONFIGURE_DEPENDS
  "*.hpp"
)
#message("lib_part_headers: ${lib_part_headers}")
set(check_lib_part_headers_included_translation_unit "#include \"lib.hpp\"\n")
foreach(lib_part_header ${lib_part_headers})
  if("${lib_part_header}" MATCHES "^\\.\\.")
    continue()
  endif()
  # assuming your include-guards are like "LIB_${file_name_no_extension_upper_case}_HPP". adjust as needed.
  string(TOUPPER "${lib_part_header}" include_guard)
  string(REPLACE "." "_" include_guard "${include_guard}")
  string(APPEND
    check_lib_part_headers_included_translation_unit
    "#ifndef LIB_${include_guard}\n  static_assert(false, \"you forgot to include ${lib_part_header}\");\n#endif\n"
    # note: if using C++23, you can use the `#error` directive
  )
endforeach()
string(APPEND
  check_lib_part_headers_included_translation_unit
  "int main() {}"
)
#message("check_lib_part_headers_included_translation_unit: ${check_lib_part_headers_included_translation_unit}")
file(WRITE "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/check_lib_part_headers_included.cpp" "${check_lib_part_headers_included_translation_unit}")
# note: if your minimum required CMake version is 3.25 or greater, you can use the SOURCE_FROM_CONTENT argument instead.
try_compile(
  check_lib_part_headers_included_result
  SOURCES "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/check_lib_part_headers_included.cpp"
  CMAKE_FLAGS "-DINCLUDE_DIRECTORIES=${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include"
  NO_CACHE
  OUTPUT_VARIABLE check_lib_part_headers_included_output
  # CXX_STANDARD <std>
  # CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED <bool>
  # CXX_EXENSIONS <bool>
)
message("check_lib_part_headers_included_result: ${check_lib_part_headers_included_result}")
if(NOT "${check_lib_part_headers_included_result}")
  message(WARNING "check_lib_part_headers_included_output: ${check_lib_part_headers_included_output}")
endif()
```

Comment: Generating the file from CMake is basically a good idea. Thanks for the suggestion! But it has the drawback that my header only library can't be used by simply setting an include path anymore. `#pragma once` is not standard, but it is supported by all compilers. Since it prevents copy and paste bugs, I don't want to go back to include guards. However, if necessary, I can combine this with a classic include guard.

Comment: @BenjaminBuch "_can't be used by simply setting an include path anymore_" how so?

Comment: The scenario is that a user of my library simply downloads the repo or includes it as @user git submodule and sets my include directory as a system header path in their build system. When doing this, my `CMakeLists.txt` is not executed and consequently the header is not generated. This can be useful if you include my lib in a project that uses a build system other than CMake.

Comment: I have realized that this is not a problem after all. I can simply copy the automatically generated main header into the project and check it in. In the CI I then check whether the main header is identical to the generated header. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @BenjaminBuch or you could modify the code I wrote to generate the generated main header into the source directory. I generate it to the build directory because (AFAIK) that's conventional for generated files. Anyhow, it would be more idiomatic to have consumers of your library import an installation of your library and the use `target_link_libraries`.